# Would this be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Recently, I was asked to participate in an evolution vs. intelligent design debate as the representative for ID. As a result, I have been busily putting together some arguments.

Being as I am a proponent of ID arguing for ID, I naturally have some bias towards my arguments. Thus, I've been looking around for objections to my arguments from evolutionists. I believe that this forum (Biology.SE) would be a good place to look for that kind of feedback. Since I have experience with other sites in the StackExchange archipelago, I thought it would be a good idea to check if my proposed question would be on-topic before I post it.

Here's a rough outline of the question:

- A brief summary of the background information for the debate (basically the first paragraph of this meta post).
- Summaries of the arguments I'm thinking of using.
- "What would be an evolutionist's responses to these arguments?"

**What I do not think the question would be:**

- A "Homework Question". I have done my due diligence researching the pertinent topics. While I suppose you could *technically* call this "help me with my homework", I don't believe it's in the sense that y'all don't like.
- A discussion. According to y'all's help center, you don't like those.
- Opinion-based. I am seeking evidence-backed responses to specific arguments.

Would my proposed question be acceptable here?

If it is not, where would you suggest I go to ask it?

Comment: You can search "intelligent design" on the main site to see existing Q&A on the topic. Most questions from that area are not received well because the ID arguments come either from uninformed reasoning or intentional bad faith. For all the claims made by ID proponents that ID should be taken seriously as science, there's no science in ID. SE is only a good fit for specific, answerable questions, so assembling your whole debate speech and expecting to get some sparring practice here would be clearly off-topic.

Comment: If you want to understand the basic weakness of ID arguments, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_design may be a good start. If you want to understand how evolution actually works, you could start from https://evolution.berkeley.edu/

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for your feedback. I'll definitely check out those resources.